# Variable-length time series - neural network

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, pattern-recognition

I have data about patient purchases - specifically, how late their fulfillment of prescriptions are, or if they filled them at all.

I want to feed this data into a neural network to classify them. Getting examplars is quite easy.

I have two ideas:

One, generate a variable-length array of floats, each representing the % lateness (so if it's a drug that should be filled every 30 days, 15 days would be a .5. I would also then feed in the purchase-period as an integer.

Second, generate a variable-length array of binaries, each representing whether a prescription was filled on that day. Again, there would be an integer representing the period.

Which of these options are preferable? Further, how can I deal with a variable-length time series? Do I need to make a different network for each different period of time? Do I just add leading or trailing zeroes, and make the input layer the size of the largest time series I could expect?